# Characterisation of point-mass distributions

Tags: measure-theory

> Let X be non-empty and consider $a : X → [0,+\infty]$. We define $\mu : 2^X → [0,\infty] $ by 
>   $$\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E} a(x)$$ for every $E\subset X$.
>   The measure (*proposition easy to prove*) on $(X,2^X)$ defined above is called **the point-mass distribution on X** induced by the **function a**.

I am trying to solve the following exercise

> Let $X\neq\emptyset$. Prove that every measure $\mu$ on $(X,2^X)$ is a point-mass distribution.

So we want to define a function $a$ on X such that $$\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E} a(x)$$ for every $E\subset X$.

If the set X is at most countable this obvious. We just have to take $a(x)=\mu(\{x\})$, for every $x\in E$ and use the countable additivity of the measure to gain the result, since $E=\cup_{x\in E}\{x\}$. But we can't use the same argument in the general case.

Which is my question.

Also, in order to solve the exercise, I tried to find the point-mass distribution for a specific measure on a general non-empty set X. So I considered the measure $\mu(E)=0$, if $E$ is countable or else is $+\infty$. Which confused me more.

Comment: I think that the specific measure you mention contradicts the statement. Are you sure there are no further demands on $\mu$? E.g. the term "distribution" indicates that we are dealing with a probability measure.

Comment: Nor in the definition of the point-mass distribution or in the exercise it states something about the value of the $\mu(X)$. There isn't any restriction on $\mu$.

Comment: Do you think that the exercise is wrong ?

Comment: Well, if it comes to a definition of $\sum_{x\in E}a(x)$ where $a(x)\in[0,\infty]$ for every $x\in E$ and $E$ is uncountable then I can only think of:$$\cdots=\sup\left\{ \sum_{x\in C}a\left(x\right)\mid C\text{ countable subset of }E\right\} $$ But this cannot give the specific measure that you mention.

Comment: I can only find one escape: a point mass distribution is **by definition** a measure such that for every pointset/singleton $\{x\}$ is measurable. That definition though makes the exercise trivial, so cannot really be trusted. Have you the disposal of a trustworthy definition? If so then I would suggest to add it to your question.

Comment: @drhab Not an escape, rather a reasoning showing the result in the exercise does not hold when X is uncountable?

Comment: @Did The (edited) definition of "point-mass distribution" makes indeed clear that there is no escape and that the exercise is not okay if there are no extra conditions (countability) on set $X$.

Comment: @drhab Yes. All in all, a good query by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The question appears as exercise #15 in page 31 of [Notes on Measure Theory](http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/%7Epapadim/measure_theory.pdf)
The discussion preceding the exercise addresses point-mass-distributions.

On page 23, the measure of a set E is defined as the supremum of the sum of measures of *finite* subsets of E, not very different from what was suggested by drhab.

This definition is not standard in measure theory and if adopted it implies that a measure on a power set must be a point mass measure. In this sense the exercise is true.

However, without this assumption the claim is wrong. Take, for example, a non-countable set and define a measure on its subsets so that countable sets have measure 0 and non-countable sets have an infinite measure.